# Google Places API: place category and place information

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

With Google Places API, I'm able to select a location and get several properties including its name, website, ph number etc.

However, i need to get the place category (food, gas station etc) but the method `getPlaceTypes()` gives me a List with integers, not a string/sequence of chars.

Also, how can I get paragraphs of info of that specific place? Is that possible? Or do I have to scrape from websites myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) you can find the Place Types supported by Google Places API. The list of integers that you are receiving is of the well known types that you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place). So you will need to transform the integers into your own text.

With Google Places is not currently possible to get detailed info of a place, not even using the more detailed [place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) that you receive when you query the Places API Web Service.

Comment: is there a method i can call to transform the integers into text?

Comment: No, you will need to implement it yourself. Take into account that you may want to draw `TYPE_BOOK_STORE` as "Book stores" and I may want to draw it as "Good old libraries"

Answer (score 0):

no api gives you the categories instead you have to explicitly provide category name in parameter for example for getting near by places.You can find categories list   here https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types